# Extract only a number of objects within an array

Tags: javascript

I am freshly working with Postman to create some tests.

Most of the `get` responses consist of big chunks of arrays with lots of objects in them (I just left two properties for ease of read, the objects have 20+ properties).

I have a script that reads through the entire response for the correct data and then it returns the result.

How can I stop the script at a certain number of objects?

```json
[
   {
      "username": "",
      "active": ""
   },
   {
      "username": "",
      "active": ""
   }
]
```

Comment: `if (numberOfObjects >= expectedNumber) { return someValue; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you (I don't know if I've understand well).

But using `filter` you can get the values with one property (you can match whatever you want) and using `slice` you will get the first N values.

So you don't have to iterate over the entire list and you can chech only these values.

Also, if you want only the number of elements that match a condition, only need to use `filter` and length.

```js
var array = [
   {
      "username": "1",
      "active": true
   },
   {
      "username": "2",
      "active": false
   },
   {
      "username": "3",
      "active": true
   }
]

var total = 1 // total documents you want
var newArray = array.filter(e => e.active).slice(0, total);

console.log(newArray)

//To know the length of elements that match the condition:
var length = array.filter(e => e.active).length
console.log(length)
```

Comment: Awesome work, thank you so much! The whole idea did help me a lot, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! If your issue has been resolved, mark answer as accepted is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

See if the below code helps

```
function processLongArray() {

  var myLongArray = [{
    "username": "active"
  }, {
    "username": "active"
  }, {
    "username": "inactive"
  }]; // and many more elements in the array

  var count = 0;
  var targetCount = 1; // stop after this number of objects
  for (var i = 0; i < myLongArray.length; i++) {
    var arrayItem = myLongArray[i];

    // condition to test if the arrayItem is considered in count
    // If no condition needed, we can directly increment the count
    if (arrayItem.username === "active") {
      count++;
    }

    if (count >= targetCount) {
      console.log("OK we are done! @ " + count);
      return count; // or any other desired value
    }
  }
}

processLongArray();
```

Comment: Awesome work, thank you so much! The whole idea did help me a lot, thank you!